# PrimeNG <p-calendar> "Invalid time" and "value.getDate is not a function" errors

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar, primeng

We use PrimeNG v6.x in our Angular project and use some calendar with time on some forms. However, although we have the following configuration and return Json from controller in dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:ss format, we encounter **"Invalid time"** and **"value.getDate is not a function"** errors. I think there must be a format conversion problem, but have not fix the problem yet by looking the issues on the web.

***Model:***

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime FinalDate { get; set; }
```

In the *.ts file we make the following configurations:

```
...
showTime: true,
hourFormat: '24'
```

The dates are returned in "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" format from the controller. But even this, get the same errors. Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a code where you declare and assign date to a p-calendar component.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The problem has been solved by using         **showseconds: true** that is not indicated on documentation pages. Regards...

Comment: good catch there @Jack. This saved me a lot of time and effort. Thanks